# Simplifying data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In my example sheets, I am trying to get it to:

1. check if "APP Activity" is yes or no, and then
2. if no, add 1 to the supervisor under "Fails".

I am able to collect all no's in columns however I am unsure if there is a way for that information to pass through a function to sort it under the correct supervisor. If there is a post about this already I would be so grateful to be pointed to it.

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A11:A; 
 QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT(D2:G9); 
 "select *"; 0); 
 "select Col4, count(Col4) 
  where Col1 ='no' 
  group by Col4"; 0); 2; 0); ))
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to replicate what you have here successfully on a stand alone spreadsheet but when I try to integrate it into what I already have it doesn't display anything but a blank cell. I have created a dummy spread sheet that is the same as mine but the data values are different, can you explain why this is happening?  I've used your formula in cell K22 on the second tab. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h410VteHeu18K8TJDtT_uSzrWxWvvSWUGMJna5eGrrA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ITG427 **try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J22:J, 
 QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT(D2:G150), 
 "select *", 0), 
 "select Col4, count(Col4) 
  where Col1 ='No' 
  group by Col4", 0), 2, 0), ))`**